# How can I use the maven rpm plugin to deploy a patch?

Tags: maven, rpm

I'm using Maven's RPM plugin to create an rpm to package up my project (Java, JSP, JavaScript) and that is working fine. I've now had to make some small changes to a JSP page and a JavaScript file. I'd like to be able to create an RPM that just does an update or patch, instead of the whole project. Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Or maybe not in the way that you're hoping for.

You can create a delta RPM, but they were designed to save bandwidth when distributing RPMs not to apply patches.  i.e. they must be served from a repository and your package manager (YUM/DNF) will take the base which is already installed, the deltas and manufacture a full new RPM and install that.

Note that to keep YUM/DNF happy, you must still supply the full new RPM so that clients that don't have the base RPM installed can do an install.

You would also have to consider what would you do for the next version that comes out?  Are you going to deltas from both previous RPMs?

So yes, you can achieve the effect that you're looking for but unless you're really looking to save bandwidth it may not help you.  Typically unless your download is slow, it takes longer to reconstitute the new RPM from the base and the delta than it does to download the full version.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense and what I suspected might be the case. Thanks for the info.